# Malliavin derivative of Ito process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $X_t= X_0 + \int_0^t \mu(s,X_s)ds + \int_0^t \sigma(s,X_s)dW_s$ where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are $C^1$ functions satisfying the usual growth restriction and $W_t$ is a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion.  Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R})$ and let $D_t$ denote the Malliavin derivative at time $t$; then how would one go about computing
$$
D_tf(X_t) =?
$$

**So Far:**
I know that if $X_t= \int_0^t \sigma(s)dW_s$ then by definition 2.2 in [these lectures by D. Nualart](https://bgsmath.cat/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Course.pdf)
$$
D_tf(X_t) = \sigma_t^T\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (X_t)\right]...
$$
but what about the general case?

Comment: The Malliavin derivative of solutions of SDEs like the one for X_t solves an equation  whose solution can be written in term of the first variation process. See https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/lecture-35-weak-differentiability-for-solutions-of-stochastic-differential-equations-and-the-existence-of-a-smooth-density/

Comment: Perfect, Thank you Fabrice.  Also, I'm a big fan of your rough path theoretic stuff. :)